# How to get next point position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to get green dot position?
Red dots position are known.

E.g. i want get mouse position + 0.5 or + 1.0 etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the Red Dots are (from left to right) Red1, Red2 and Red3 and of type Vector2

```
Vector2 LeftGreen = ((Red1 - Red2) * 4.5f) + Red2;
Vector2 RightGreen= ((Red3 - Red1) * 2.5f) + Red3;
```

Comment: RedPoint1 (left) + 4.5f = GreenPoint1 (left)       
RedPoint2 (right) + 2.5f = GreenPoint2 (right)

Comment: do you mean add 4.5 or 2.5 respectively to each axis of the dots or do you mean the distance to the center dot should increase by that? @MatthewP

Comment: 4.5 -  it is distance between RedPoint1 and GreenPoint1
2.5 -  it is distance between RedPoint2 and GreenPoint2

Comment: @MatthewP I edited the answer to match what I think your comment means (however, your english is rather bad so I may still be wrong)

Comment: Even with my bad English you understood what I needed. Thanks!